# Segmentation fault when assigning to struct

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, shared-memory

[shm_ipc.c](https://pastebin.com/udGJ6K0A)

[operations.h](https://pastebin.com/7FJFBKJe)

I'm experiencing a segmentation fault when assigning to an integer variable.

```
typedef struct shared_data {
    /// Used by controller to notify worker when a task is available.
    sem_t controller_semaphore;

    /// Used by worker to notify controller when a result is available.
    sem_t worker_semaphore;

    /// Operation assigned by controller, telling worker what to do. 
    operation_t operation;

    /// Parameters for the operation, assigned by controller and read by worker.
    double lhs, rhs;

    /// Result of operation, assigned by worker and read by controller.
    double result;
} shared_data_t;

typedef struct shared_memory {
    /// The name of the shared memory object.
    const char* name;

    /// The file descriptor used to manage the shared memory object.
    int fd;

    /// Address of the shared data block. 
    shared_data_t* data;
} shared_memory_t;

bool create_shared_object( shared_memory_t* shm, const char* share_name ) {
    int shm_fd;

    shm_unlink(share_name);

    shm->name = share_name;

 
    shm_fd = shm_open(share_name,O_CREAT | O_RDWR,0666);
    

    if(shm_fd == -1){  
        shm->data = NULL;
        return false;
    }else{
        shm->fd = shm_fd;
    }

    if(ftruncate(shm->fd,sizeof(struct shared_data))== -1){
        shm->data = NULL;
        return false;
    }else{
        shm = mmap(0,SHMSZ,PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,shm->fd,0);
    }

    sem_init( &shm->data->controller_semaphore, 1, 0 );
    sem_init( &shm->data->worker_semaphore, 1, 0 );

    return true;
}
```

The segfault is thrown when assigning the value of the shm_open to shm->fd.

**shm calling code**

```
srand( 42 );
printf( "Controller starting.\n" );

shared_memory_t shm;

if ( create_shared_object( &shm, "/xyzzy_123" )){
    // Do stuff here
}
```

It is returning 3 so I know I'm not attempting to input a negative value into the field. I've been banging my head against a wall trying to figure this out.

Please help.

Comment: You are checking shm_fd without assigning it.  Can you also post the calling code - how is shm created?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. The segfault occurs during that assignment. I've also posting the calling code

Comment: Try creating your shared memory in a local directory - put a . in front of the /.  I'm guessing that you don't have write access to the top level directory.

Comment: Now it seems to be returning -1 instead...

Comment: @RogueTamago if `shm_open` returns -1, check the error number in `errno`. I your case it's likely that you don't have access to the `/` directory. Try `"/tmp/xyzzy_123"` instead of `"/xyzzy_123"`

Comment: Still haven't fixed this issue. I've uploaded both the file and the header. the compile flags used are 'gcc shm_ipc.c -lrt -lpthread -o shm'

Comment: @RogueTamago If you're on any platform that's remotely standard, do not use `-lpthread`. Instead, use `-pthread`.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     if(shm->fd = shm_open(share_name,O_CREAT | O_RDWR,0666)<0){
> ```

This error is easy to miss - if `shm_open` succeeds, not the *file descriptor* is assigned to `shm->fd`, but the result 0 of the `<0` comparison. I suggest to write this more clearly without risking such an error:

```
    shm->fd = shm_open(share_name, O_CREAT|O_RDWR, 0666);
    if (shm->fd < 0)
    {
```

Then, with

> ```
>         shm = mmap(0,SHMSZ,PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,shm->fd,0);
> ```

you probably meant

```
        shm->data = mmap(0, SHMSZ, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm->fd, 0);
```